# Run exe with arguments on remote machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

This one is ruining me. Something that I'm pretty sure should be simple just isn't working and it's probably just a single quotation/character out of place.

There's a lync/Skype tool called sefautil.exe that does all kinds of marvelous things the webGUI doesn't. A typical command would be:

```
C:\Program Files\Skype for Business Server 2015\ResKit>sefautil.exe /server:sfbpool01.domain.local sip:user1@domain.local /setfwddestination:user2@domain.local /enablefwdimmediate
```

This works fine when remoted onto any of the machines, but I'm really struggling to run it via remote PowerShell.

Whatever commands I try via `invoke-command` either give me a standard `/?` response or nothing at all. I've passed the args via `-ArgumentList`, as a variable, as anything I can think of and it's just not working.

What makes the thing even more tasking as if you run without admin rights, you won't ever get any results. The command has to be ran as an admin. Now I can quite easily put an admin mode checker into my script, but if it's just as easy to send the command as admin I'll take it.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked event logs on the local machine for any powershell related errors?

Comment: Have you tried with [psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)?

Comment: Try this: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer01 -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Skype for Business Server 2015\ResKit\sefautil.exe" -ArgumentList "/server:sfbpool01.domain.local", "sip:user1@domain.local", "/setfwddestination:user2@domain.local", "/enablefwdimmediate" }`

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: @vrdse - Sadly no errors. Either nothing entirely or a standard /? dump.

Comment: @JamesC. - Didn't work I'm afraid. This gives no response at all. Just pings to the next line as if nothing happened

Comment: @qbanet359 - Feel like there's promise here but probably getting the syntax wrong.

    
           
           c:\temp\psexec.exe -accepteula \\Computer01 "C:\Temp\sefautil.exe" "/server:sfbpool01.Domain.local sip:user1@domain.local"

This command will give me a sefautil.exe /? follow by:

    c:\temp\psexec.exe : Connecting to Computer01...
At line:2 char:12
+            c:\temp\psexec.exe -accepteula \\Computer01 "C:\Temp\sefautil.exe" "/s ..

Comment: @trebleCode - The eventlog is completely empty

Comment: Remove some of the quotes. Try psexec like this: 

`c:\temp\psexec.exe -accepteula \\Computer01 "C:\Temp\sefautil.exe /server:sfbpool01.Domain.local sip:user1@domain.local"`

Comment: Are you expecting this application to display a window for the locally logged on user?

Comment: @qbanet359 - I get this:

PsExec could not start C:\Program Files\Skype for Business Server 2015\ResKit\SEFAUtil.exe /server:sfbpool01.domain.local sip:user1@domain.local on computer1:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @HeedfulCrayon - Normally you'd get a result spam. Not sure if it's necessary mind, as long as it does the piece of work, it's easy to check via other methods.

Comment: Okay let’s try another approach. Could you put your entire sefautil.exe in a .bat script locally on “computer01”? Say it’s at c:\temp\sefautil.bat. Then from your PC run `C:\Temp\psexec.exe \\Computer01 C:\temp\sefautil.bat`

Answer (score 2):

@qbanet359

I've gone about it a different way which feels a little cheap, but it does work so can't complain.

I've created a scheduled task on the server hosting sefautil.exe to run a batch file under elevated permissions - I've called it sefautil. 

I also copied sefaUTIL.exe to C:\TEMP on the server.

Then in my PowerShell script I'm using:

```
$SERVER = "\\computer1\c$\temp"
"cd \" | Out-File "$SERVER\sefautiltest.bat" -Encoding unicode
"cmd /c C:\Temp\sefautil.exe /server:sfbpool01.ad.leics.gov.uk sip:dols.team@leics.gov.uk" | Out-File "$SERVER\sefautiltest.bat" -Append
gc $SERVER\sefautiltest.bat | out-file $server\sefautil.bat -encoding ascii
Invoke-Command -Credential $CREDS -ComputerName computer 01-ScriptBlock { schtasks /Run /TN sefautil }
```

It's almost certainly a long winded way of doing this, but it does work.

Thanks for giving me a fresh perspective on things.

Comment: Hey whatever works. Glad I could help point you the right way

Answer (score 0):

A Little late to the party, but I'm sure a lot of other SfB-Admins will struggle here as well.

This is how I made it work:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Global:SefaUtilServer -ScriptBlock {&'C:\Program Files\Skype for Business Server 2015\ResKit\SEFAUtil.exe' '/server:feserver.domain.local' $args[0] "/enablefwdnoanswer" "/setfwddestination:$($args[1])" "/callanswerwaittime:$($args[2])"} -Credential $Global:LyncSchedTask_Cred  -Authentication Credssp -ArgumentList @($UserSip.replace("sip:",""),$Destination,$Delay)
```

Hint: make sure, that you don't run in the "Powershell Double Hop issue". SefaUtil will make a Connection to a Frontend Server (I assume it's the one with the CMS located) to make the actual changes in the DB. (See my answer on TechNet: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5d4c4f90-1b40-4742-ae4b-c2e1a62a0adb/running-sefautil-remotely?forum=lyncdeploy#da6b82b9-cada-420b-a7a7-2110c0ed2280 (by cwa.cloud)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with below.
Basically create a batch file with powershell on the SfB server and then run it with psexec to use the System account (psexec had been copied to the server).
Make sure you insert your own server's name where it has "servername" and run the script with an account that has sufficient permissions. Then call the script with the correct parameters.

BTW, I've noticed it can return an error code of 1 if the forwarding is already in place.

```
param ([string]$FwdUser,[string]$DestUser)

#skype for business phone forwarding
#create a batch file to run the command, run it as system with psexec and remove the batch file afterwards. sefautil does not cooperate with remote execution
$sefautilcmd = "`"C:\Program Files\Skype for Business Server 2015\ResKit\SEFAUtil.exe`" /Server:servername.headoffice.novationleasing.com.au " + $FwdUser + " /setfwddestination:" + $DestUser + " /enablefwdimmediate"
New-Item \\servername\c$\temp\tempfwd.bat
Set-Content \\servername\c$\temp\tempfwd.bat $sefautilcmd
Invoke-Command -ComputerName servername -ScriptBlock {C:\temp\psexec.exe -s -accepteula c:\temp\tempfwd.bat}
Remove-Item \\servername\c$\temp\tempfwd.bat
```